# To post a tweet using npm package Twitter in node.js (not working)

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, node-modules

I would like to post a tweet using npm package [Twitter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter) in `node.js`envronment. I am able to post a simple text tweet when I'm using `client.post` method as shown in the documentation [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter#rest-api). The problem is when I try to obtain the status object using `promise.then()`, I couldn't post. The output of my promise is `status` object which is a simple `url`. Also, I do not receive any error or request response for my code below.

```js
const Twitter = require('twitter'); 
const config = require('./config.js'); 
// passing client details from config file to new T class 
const T = new Twitter(config); 

T.post('statuses/update', getData(url).then((data)=>{
    let status = JSON.stringify(data);
    console.log(status)
    return status
}), function(error, tweet, response) {
    if(!error){
        console.log("tweet successfully sent", tweet.text);
    }
    else (error);
 });
// console.log(status)
// "http://example.com/"
```

I believe that I am doing some mistake in passing data from my promise object.Can someone help me correct this? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to do asynchronous opertion while passing a paramater so which eventually sends promise. You can restructure your code like this as `twitter` package also supports promise.

```
const Twitter = require('twitter'); 
const config = require('./config.js'); 
// passing client details from config file to new T class 
const T = new Twitter(config); 

getData(url)
 .then(data => JSON.stringify(data))
 .then(status => T.post('statuses/update', {status :status}))
 .then(tweet => console.log("tweet successfully sent", tweet.text))
 .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks but I still have an error `Unhandled promise rejection`. Also with above code I couldn't recieve any response or error message, if my HTTP request was rejected.

Comment: @newbie you need to add a catch at the end to see the errors. I have edited my response.

Comment: If this answer your question , please mark it as answer for other people references

Comment: Thanks, I was trying as stated in documentation - `.catch(function (error) {
    throw error;
  })`. Do you know why this does not work in above code?

Comment: You are throwing the exception after catching it which is equivalent to not catching the exception